# Vista encimada al ejecutar código en pantalla completa en la revisión de ediciones

Tags: bug, respuesta, ediciones, stack-snippets

Hace unos minutos estaba modificando [una respuesta mía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443281/por-qu%C3%A9-al-metodo-document-body-appendchild-se-le-tiene-que-especificar-que-es/443283#443283) para añadir más detalles, sin embargo, durante la edición coloqué algunos *snippets* y al momento de ejecutarlos en la revisión de ediciones y acceder a la pantalla completa se me encimó el resultado con el nav lateral

Adjunto capturas de lo que me refiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El único CSS que estaba aplicando en esa respuesta es el siguiente:

```css
div {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: green;
}
```

## EDIT

Es cuando accedo a esta parte:

[image: Lugar del bug]

Ya lo intenté en los navegadores: **Brave, Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge** y en todos me aparece de esa manera.

**Nota:** No tengo instalados *plugins* que puedan causar este comportamiento.

Comment: no será que tienes algún plugin en el navegador que interfiera con el css??? intenta nuevamente sin pluggins si los tienes...

Comment: No, ya lo acabo de comprobar en 4 navegadores distintos, todos me dan la misma vista.

Comment: Uso **Opera** (también lo comprobé en Microsoft Edge), acabo de probar esto y la vista completa me aparece normal, comprueba tus extensiones o la versión de tu navegador.

Comment: Se supone que tengo las versiones actuales de los navegadores y en dos navegadores no tengo ni extensiones. Supongo que si sólo me pasa a mí y sólo en esa no hay problema

Comment: Suena contraintuitivo pero lo he visto pasar... algún antivirus más inquieto de lo normal (uno como Avast o AVG)